# MySQL SUM related to parent query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to put together a query to aggregate some information into a view, and am having trouble working out how to get that data I need from a couple of different tables. I'll start by describing the 3 tables I'm working with.

I have artists, which is as follows:

```
Ref | Artist
  1 | Metallica
```

I have tracks:

```
Filename | Title             | artist_ref
     001 | Sad But True      |       1
     002 | Through The Never |       1
```

And lastly I have popularity:

```
Filename | week | month | quarter
     001 |   23 |    42 |     138
     002 |    4 |    23 |      42
```

What I'm trying to do is get an aggregated popularity table formatted as so:

```
artist_ref | week | month | quarter
         1 |   27 |    65 |     180
```

I understand I'll have to use some kind of subquery and SUM, but my knowledge of this area is fairly limited. Any help is hugely appreciated as I'm finding this a bit of a brain buster!

Comment: how artist record related with tracks and popularity?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed it off. I've edited the post to include the information. "artists" isn't directly associated with popularity, but it is with tracks, and so is popularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select artist_ref, SUM(week) as week,
SUM(month) as month,SUM(quarter) as quarter
FROM tracks LEFT JOIN popularity
USING (Filename)
group by artist_ref;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eca05/1)**

Comment: Excellent! With a bit of fiddling indexes that works an absolute charm. Thanks loads for your help. Here's my final query:

Select artist_ref, IFNULL(SUM(week), 0) as week, IFNULL(SUM(month), 0) as month, IFNULL(SUM(quarter), 0) as quarter
FROM tracks
LEFT JOIN popularity USING (Filename)
GROUP BY artist_ref